# html header the width of text only

Tags: html

Headers seem to take up the size of the parent container vs just the size of the text inside of it. So when I do a hover effect it doesn't just happen when over the text but over the width of the container on the same line as the text. I only want to do the hover effect when exactly over the text of the header. Below shows a big red bar that is wider than the headers themselves.

https://jsfiddle.net/1y8n9wuk/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-sm-4" id="title">
                <h1>Dead Anyway</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4" id="menuOptions">
                <!-- testing: list the maps to load -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="maps">Maps</label>
                    <select id="maps" class="form-control input-small">
                        <option>Start.map</option>
                        <option>medium</option>
                        <option>large</option>
                    </select> 
                </div>

                <h3 style="background-color: red;" id="newGame">New Game</h3>
                <h3 id="savedGame">Saved Game</h3>
                <h3 id="options">Options</h3>
                <h3 id="exit">Exit</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So wrap the text in a span and apply the CSS to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the tag 'display' property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

In this case you would want to set the display property to:

```
<h3 style="background-color: red; display:inline;" id="newGame">New Game</h3>
```

Currently the header tags inherits a display value of 'block'.